# Matplotlib: Secondary axis shares values with both of the main axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, multiple-axes

I have added a secondary x-axis to my plot. The aim is just to provide another snippet of information to the data shown by the primary x and y axes. As you can see from the attached image, I have used **twiny()** command to share the y-axis and **get_shared_x_axes().join(ax1,ax2)** to align the secondary axis with the primary x-axis.

However, this results in plotting duplicate data. What I really need is in fact for the rectangular markers to provide another scale of information given by the circular markers in the attached image. Matplotlib examples handle this situation by writing a function for instance to convert Celsius degrees to Fahrenheit. In my case, there is no apparent relationship, just scatter data points. Could you please point me towards to the right direction? Many thanks!

[image: Image to visualize the problem]

Comment: I think you want the third example here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/secondary_axis.html

Comment: It seems that this technique requires a newer mpl version, so couldn't try it out unfortunately. Also, not sure if interpolation can help really in this situation.